# Change auto-renaming in guake

Tags: 14.04, python, guake

Is there any way to remove path from tab name in guake?
Usually I open several hosts in different tabs and I rename them all according to the host name. It is annoying to make the same action on every new tab.
Default behavior (vte.get_window_title()) is not convenient because tab name has path in it. I don't need any path in tab, and also usually names with path are very long.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I've already answered this question somewhere but I couldn't find it, so this answer (and this question) are possible duplicates.
Anyway, the command you're looking for is probably

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/guake/general/use_vte_titles --type boolean false
```

This always does it for me.